# Why do we need to check condition when creating phytree in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was reading the `phytree` function in Matlab ([code here](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/bioinfo/bioinfo/@phytree/phytree.m)). The code below confuses me. The matrix `B` is the input matrix of size `(n-1)*2`, where `n` is the number of leaves. Here, `B` indicates how the phytree is created: the i-th row corresponds to the i-th branch, which is the two children of the i-th branch. Can anyone tell me why do we need to check the first condition in the following?

```
% test B
if sum(diff(sort(B(:)))~=1) || (min(B(:))~=1)
    error('Bioinfo:phytree:IncompleteTree','Branch architecture is not complete')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this up.

1. `sort(B(:))` returns a column vector of the elements of `B` in ascending order. See: [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).
2. `diff(sort(B(:)))` returns a vector of differences between subsequent elements of step 1. See: [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).
3. `diff(sort(B(:)))~=1` returns a vector of `logical` values: `false` (`0`) if the difference result from step 2 is `1` or `true` (`1`) other. See: [logical operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html).
4. `sum(diff(sort(B(:)))~=1)` sums the vector of `logical` values from step 3. If all values were `false` (`0`), the sum should be zero. If not, the error will be triggered. See: [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html).

In other words, this statements checks that the indices in `B` are spaced equally by one. The second statement, `min(B(:))~=1`, checks that the smallest index is one. Thus, `B` must contain integers from `1` to `numel(B)`. This is requirement defined by the function itself and is detailed in the help.